# Powershell - Replace add_Click link on LinkLabel

Tags: powershell

I am creating a PowerShell GUI that uses a link label. My code for this link is

```
$ExLinkLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.LinkLabel
$ExLinkLabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(15,130)
$ExLinkLabel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(150,20)
$ExLinkLabel.LinkColor = "BLUE"
$ExLinkLabel.ActiveLinkColor = "RED"
$ExLinkLabel.Text = "Link Example"
$ExLinkLabel.add_Click({[system.Diagnostics.Process]::start("https://google.com")})
$Form.Controls.Add($ExLinkLabel)
```

Now say I want to change it another website later in the code based on certain conditions, I tried doing this:

```
$ExLinkLabel.add_Click({[system.Diagnostics.Process]::start("https://yahoo.com")})
```

The problem that this now has two links open, both google and then yahoo.

Is there a way to clear or just replace that first link with my new one?

Thank you

Comment: Then why not put the url in a variable that gets its value depending on the conditions you will implement? Then in the `Add_Click({..})` event handler you can put `[system.Diagnostics.Process]::start($script:MyUrlVariable)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding an event handler with an `.add_<EventName>()` method call does just that: It *adds* an additional event handler, of which there can be many.

**In order to *replace* an event handler, you must first *remove* its old incarnation with `.remove_<EventName>()`, and then add the new incarnation with `.add_<EventName>()`.**

To that end, you must store the original incarnation in a *variable* that you can later pass to the `.remove_EventName>()` call:

```
# Define the original event handler, store it in a variable,
# and add it to the control.
$currEventHandler = { Start-Process https://google.com }
$ExLinkLabel.add_Click($currEventHandler)

# ...

# Remove the current event handler...
$ExLinkLabel.remove_Click($currEventHandler)
# ... and add the new one:
$currEventHandler = { Start-Process https://yahoo.com }
$ExLinkLabel.add_Click($currEventHandler)
```

<sup>Note that I've replaced `[system.Diagnostics.Process]::start($url)` with a simpler, PowerShell-idiomatic call to the `Start-Process` cmdlet.</sup>

---

In your simple case, where the two event handlers only differ by the URL they open, consider the alternative recommended by [Theo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9898643/theo):

- Retain the original event handler and make it retrieve the URL to open from a *variable* defined outside the event handler, namely in the script scope. That way, all you need to do is to update the variable.

```
# Set the original URL
$url = 'https://google.com'

# Due to PowerShell's dynamic scoping, the event-handler script
# block - even though it runs in a *child* scope - sees the
# script scope's definition of variable $url
# You can make this cross-scope access explicit by using $script:url
# (If you wanted to *update* the variable from inside the child 
# scope $script:url *must* be used.)
$ExLinkLabel.add_Click({ Start-Process $url })

# ...

# Update the variable, after which the event handler will 
# use the new URL.
$url = 'https://yahoo.com'
```